# Powershell: Edit Excel File is very slow

Tags: performance, excel, powershell

I'm working on a powershell script, that checks excel values in a specific row and if the value match to an array, it should write some text next to it.

The script is working, but it's very slow because it has to check over 5000 values.
I hope some of you can help me to speed up my script?? Maybe I'm doing something wrong...I'm still a beginner.

```
#Open Excel File
#------------------------------------

$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault

$xl = New-Object -comobject "excel.application"
$xl.visible = $false
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $false

$WorkBook = $xl.WorkBooks.Open("C:\test.xls")



#Definition Variables
#------------------------------------

$arrayCheckCell = @(
"Test 1", <# 1 #>
"Test 2", <# 2 #>
"Test 3", <# 3 #>
"Test 4", <# 4 #>
"Test 5", <# 5 #>
"Test 6", <# 6 #>
"Test 7", <# 7 #>
"Test 8", <# 8 #>
"Test 9"  <# 9 #>
) 

$ArrayInsertText = @(
"Some Text 1", <# 1 #>
"Some Text 2", <# 2 #>
"Some Text 3", <# 3 #>
"Some Text 4", <# 4 #>
"Some Text 5", <# 5 #>
"Some Text 6", <# 6 #>
"Some Text 7", <# 7 #>
"Some Text 8", <# 8 #>
"Some Text 9" <# 9 #>

)

[int]$rowC = 3
[int]$line = 2

$arrayCheckCellCount = $arrayCheckCell.Count


#Check values in row C and insert text in row D
#---------------------------------------------------


for ($i = 1; $i -lt 5000 ; $i++) 
{

    for ($i2=0; $i2 -lt $arrayCheckCellCount ; $i2++) 
    {

                if ($xl.cells.item($line, $rowC).Text -match $arrayCheckCell[$i2]) 
                 {

                    $xl.Range("D$line").value2 = $ArrayInsertText[$i2]

                 }


    }

 $line++
}



#Other definitions
#----------------------------------
 $xl.selection.autofilter(1, "*")
 $table=$xl.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.add( 1,$xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange,0,1)
 $xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()


#Save File and kill Excel Process
#----------------------------------

$WorkBook.SaveAs("C:\test.xls", $xlFixedFormat)
$xl.Quit() 

Start-Sleep 2
$ExcelProcess = get-process excel
$ExcelProcess | foreach {stop-process ($_.id)}
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:to accommodate match like function for the keys.
There are some minor errors in your code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 5000 ; $i++) 
{
.....
$line++
}
```

Should really be

```
for ($line = 1; $line -lt 5000 ; $line++) 
{
.....
}
```

otherwise the $i variable is pointless as it is not being used for anything else but incrementation.

To speed things up you can use hash tables which are *much* more efficient memory constructs and you can find out about them here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx.

Replace between `#Definition Variables` and `#Other definitions` with the following code, on my sample data the new code runs more than 5 times faster.

```
#Definition Variables
#------------------------------------

$hCell = @{}
$hCell.Add("Some Text 1","Some Text 1")
$hCell.Add("Some Text 2","Some Text 2")
$hCell.Add("Some Text 3","Some Text 3")
$hCell.Add("Some Text 4","Some Text 4")
$hCell.Add("Some Text 5","Some Text 5")
$hCell.Add("Some Text 6","Some Text 6")
$hCell.Add("Some Text 7","Some Text 7")
$hCell.Add("Some Text 8","Some Text 8")
$hCell.Add("Some Text 9","Some Text 9")
$hCell.Add("Some Text 10","Some Text 10")


[int]$rowC = 3
[int]$line = 2

$arrayCheckCellCount = $arrayCheckCell.Count


#Check values in row C and insert text in row D
#---------------------------------------------------

$k = $hCell.Keys
for ($line = 1; $line -lt 5000 ; $line++) 
{
                if ($k -match ($xl.cells.item($line, $rowC).Text)) 
             {

                $xl.Range("D$line").value2 = $hCell.Item($xl.cells.item($line, $rowC).Text)

             }

}



#Other definitions
#----------------------------------
```

Comment: I tried it your way, it's much faster but I need a function like "-match" because it has to check if the cell value Begins with "Some_text_1_". So that all similar values get the same input. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I've amended the answer, individual cells will now be compared to the _Keys_ collection derived from the original hash table. _I think_ it should work but mileage may vary..

Comment: I tried the new code, but it's not working. The cells in D remain empty. Do you have another idea? Thx for your help =)

Comment: Hmm, it works for me using PS4 or PS2..do you get any errors? The _if_ statement must be failing, you can see what is going by inserting ``Write-Host ("Comparing keys: " + $k + "`r`non line " + $line + "`r`nwith text: " + $xl.cells.item($line, $rowC).Text)`` just above the if statement.

Comment: I'm using PS3, but I guess that should still work? I don't get an error. I think It's because of the -match Operator. If I write in one of these hashtable the exact Name and value, it works. When I write "Some-Test-1-" and it has to search for this kind of entry "Some-Test-1-Test-1", it's seems not to find it.

Comment: The match will only work if the string you are comparing on right hand side is shorter than the key on the left so not suitable for your case. Not sure if there is a way around it without using _GetEnumerator()_ function which will negate all the benefits of using a hashtable.

Comment: You mean "if ($k -match ($xl.cells.item($line, $rowC).Text))" the Cell Value has to be shorter than the variable $k ? So why not just write it the other way "if (($xl.cells.item($line, $rowC).Text) -match $k)" ?

Comment: This is not going to work due to the way match works in this scenario. You are comparing string to KeyCollection, so checking whether a string is inside KeyCollection - if you flip them around you are effectively asking "is the key collection inside the string", which is not going to work.

Comment: How can I use the getEnumerator function? Or maybe change my script like I posted below?

Comment: Using _GetEnumerator()_ is on par with using an array so no better than your original code.

Comment: Maybe it's still a Little bit faster than my original code...could you help me to use the GetEnumerator() function?

Comment: You will have better luck saving your dataset as a CSV as this will be much faster than working with Excell COM object. You can read about it here [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) or the interweb as there are plenty of resources out there. Using _GetEnumerator()_ is not going to be better than your original array as you would have to call _GetEnumerator() _ on every new line of Excell being read.

Comment: I will test it and post it how it worked =) thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're checking 5000 * 9 (arrayCheckCell) fields. In my test I was getting 1.75 seconds for each group of 9 or 5000 * 1.75 seconds.

Do you really need to check 5000 fields?

what I've done in the past when I don't know how many fields in a row or column I need to check I set a max limit of empty fields (for example '5'). If I hit 5 empty fields I break out.

ex:

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty( $($xl.cells.item($line, $rowC).Text) ) 
{ $EmptyContiguousFilds++ } 
else 
{ $EmptyContiguousFilds= 0 }

if ($EmptyContiguousFilds -gt $MAXEMPTYFIELDS) { break; }
```

Comment: Oh thx I can really use this piece of script;) How can I implement this in my existing code? Can you help me?